# How to wrap a command in zsh with arbitrary function

Tags: zsh

So I often run some commands that takes a long time and outputs a lot of stuff. By the time I come back at it, I forget what arguments I run it with and have to search the console for it. I would like to wrap all my commands with a function that print the command line after the command is finished, or even more fancy stuff like run time etc.

For example,

```
$ time ls
...
ls --color=tty  0.00s user 0.01s system 12% cpu 0.062 total
```

What I wanted is to achieve the same result without having to type "time".

```
$ ls
...
ls --color=tty  0.00s user 0.01s system 12% cpu 0.062 total
```

Comment: Please tag for bash *or* zsh, not both. They're not compatible shells.

Comment: And right now, this question is pretty vague -- it's hard to tell if an answer is or is not complete and responsive. It would be helpful to show what you've tried and how it fails, or at least to give *specific* requirements as opposed to examples of what you might generally want to do in theory.

Comment: (For instance, if you just want to have your prompt print the text of the last command you ran, you don't need a function wrapper for that at all; if that is in fact your goal, the question can and should be reworded to ask the question more explicitly and directly).

Comment: (Similarly, if you want to wrap *every* command in a function, that's a different question from how to wrap *a specific* command in a function; I've interpreted you as asking the latter, but I'm not 100% certain that that interpretation is correct).

Answer (score 2):

If you set the `REPORTTIME` variable to a non-negative number, any command whose combined user and system time is greater than the value will display the same output as if you had run it with `time` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

```
timed_run_and_print() {
  time "$@"
  printf "Just finished running: " >&2
  printf '%q ' "$@" >&2
  printf '\n' >&2
}
```

...thereafter:

```
% timed_run_and_print sleep 3
  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 3.006 total
Just finished running: sleep 3
```